# Run two methods parallel when page starts

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have two methods which I have to run in parallel when the page starts.

```
public Page1()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    loadtest();
    loadtest2();
}
```

These methods take image from my MySQL database and store that in a variable which can be called later.

```
public void loadtest()
{
    string query = "select*from question where id='" + 1 + "'";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string qid = myReader.GetInt32("id").ToString();

            byte[] imgg1q1 = (byte[])(myReader["question"]);
            byte[] imgg2q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt1"]);
            byte[] imgg3q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt2"]);
            byte[] imgg4q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt3"]);
            byte[] imgg5q1 = (byte[])(myReader["opt4"]);

            MemoryStream mstreamq1 = new MemoryStream(imgg1q1);
            MemoryStream mstream1q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg2q1);
            MemoryStream mstream2q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg3q1);
            MemoryStream mstream3q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg4q1);
            MemoryStream mstream4q1 = new MemoryStream(imgg5q1);

            q1.BeginInit();
            q1.StreamSource = mstreamq1;
            q1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q1.EndInit();

            q1opt1.BeginInit();
            q1opt1.StreamSource = mstream1q1;
            q1opt1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q1opt1.EndInit();

            q1opt2.BeginInit();
            q1opt2.StreamSource = mstream2q1;
            q1opt2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q1opt2.EndInit();

            q1opt3.BeginInit();
            q1opt3.StreamSource = mstream3q1;
            q1opt3.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q1opt3.EndInit();

            // Assign the Source property of your image
            option_3.Source = q1opt3;

            q1opt4.BeginInit();
            q1opt4.StreamSource = mstream4q1;
            q1opt4.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q1opt4.EndInit();
        }

        conDataBase.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

public void loadtest2()
{
    string query = "select*from question where id='" + 2 + "'";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string qid = myReader.GetInt32("id").ToString();

            byte[] imgg1 = (byte[])(myReader["question"]);
            byte[] imgg2 = (byte[])(myReader["opt1"]);
            byte[] imgg3 = (byte[])(myReader["opt2"]);
            byte[] imgg4 = (byte[])(myReader["opt3"]);
            byte[] imgg5 = (byte[])(myReader["opt4"]);

            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg1);
            MemoryStream mstream1 = new MemoryStream(imgg2);
            MemoryStream mstream2 = new MemoryStream(imgg3);
            MemoryStream mstream3 = new MemoryStream(imgg4);
            MemoryStream mstream4 = new MemoryStream(imgg5);

            q2.BeginInit();
            q2.StreamSource = mstream;
            q2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q2.EndInit();

            q2opt1.BeginInit();
            q2opt1.StreamSource = mstream1;
            q2opt1.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q2opt1.EndInit();

            q2opt2.BeginInit();
            q2opt2.StreamSource = mstream2;
            q2opt2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q2opt2.EndInit();

            q2opt3.BeginInit();
            q2opt3.StreamSource = mstream3;
            q2opt3.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q2opt3.EndInit();

            q2opt4.BeginInit();
            q2opt4.StreamSource = mstream4;
            q2opt4.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            q2opt4.EndInit();
        }

        conDataBase.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

I have tried the methods given on the Internet but it does not display questions when I run them in parallel. I have used the threads to run the methods but the variables get empty and do not display anything.
I have also used `Parallel.Invoke(() => loadtest(),() =>loadtest2());`
but this is also of no use; it saves values for the first function which in above case is `loadtest()` and does not save value for the second function, i.e `loadtest2()`.

Answer (score 0):

**One Way**

```
public Page1()
    { 
         InitializeComponent();
         var test1 = Task.Run(() => loadtest());
         var test2 = Task.Run(() => loadtest2());
         Task.WhenAll(test1,test2);
    }
```

**Other way is**

```
public Page1()
{ 
     InitializeComponent();
     Parallel.Invoke(new Action(loadtest),new Action(loadtest2));
}
```

Comment: i tried both the methods but the task method is not displaying questions i don't know the varibles are empty when i make them display . they work completely fine when i write them simply ....like .............loadtest(); loadtest2();.............and the next with parallel invoke it saves images for first written method in above case its loadtest() but again for loadtest2 it gets empty

Comment: try locking may be some interference in code. But I think the code is running parallely

Comment: yeah i have tested the method ....code is running parallely but its just not saving the values in the variables.....how can i lock the values...

Comment: Your code need refactoring.  Second just try to save different bitmaps in different methods and see the effect